# How to convert a String to custom data type

Tags: java, type-conversion

I need to convert a String to a Custom Data Type for a key. I am using Derby(it'd old, I know). I have two tables, linked with primary and foreign keys. The second table only accepts a parameter if it is the same as the first table(`public Roster setGameID(Games GamesID)`), this is in the second table.

I need to convert the String to Type Games. This method doesn't work:

```
Games Test = (Games)GamesID;
```

GamesID is the String Input.

Thanks Again!

Comment: You need a container to store the string.  Create an attribute in Games to store the string.

Comment: So, it must be like this, private String GamesID? and change the parameter?

Comment: How could you convert a tree into a wardrobe? Just casting the Tree to Wardrobe won't work: a tree is not a wardrobe. But you can cut the tree, make boards out of it, and assemble the boards to construct a wardrobe. Same with your string, I guess: you need to parse it, extract information out of it, and construct a Games object with that information. You should learn basics of OO and types before doing database programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the error.

The one java class is dependent on the independent one. This is what I needed to do.

```
obj1.setId(GameCode);
```

Pass the string to the independent class. GameCode is the String.

Then pass the independent class to the dependent class(obj1)

```
obj.setGameregfor(obj1);
```

Now it inserts into the other table without any hassle.

Answer (score 0):

It should be something like

```
    class Games{
   private String gamesId;

    setGamesId(String id)
    {
       gamesId=id;
    }
    ..
    }
```

and then

```
Games games=new Games()
games.setGamesId("xyz");
```

or have constructor to take this as an argument.